# Как предотвратить удаление textview при перетаскивании объекта методом drag and drop

Tags: android, drag-n-drop

Activity  визуально разделено на две части, а именно 2 layout-а: слева area1, справа area2. При старте активити в area1 помещаются цифры (от нуля до 9). Пользователь может кликнуть на цифру и перетащить ее на area2. При этом цифра удаляется с area1. Как исправить код так, чтобы пользователь и перетаскивал цифру с поля area1 на area2 , и при этом эта цифра с поля area1 не удалялась?

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener{
    LinearLayout area1, area2;
    TypedArray arrayResources;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams;    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        area1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.area1);
        area2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.area2);

        arrayResources = getResources().obtainTypedArray(
                R.array.resicon);

              for (int i = 0; i < arrayResources.length(); i++) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
           textView.setText(arrayResources.getText(i));

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            int textViewGravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;

            lParams.gravity = textViewGravity;
            lParams.setMargins(10,5,5,5);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            textView.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.size1));
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            textView.setOnTouchListener(this);
            area1.addView(textView, lParams);
        }            

        arrayResources.recycle();

        area1.setOnDragListener(myOnDragListener);
        area2.setOnDragListener(myOnDragListener);
    }
    OnDragListener myOnDragListener = new OnDragListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {   

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                   case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                   View view = (View)event.getLocalState();    

                    LinearLayout oldParent = (LinearLayout)view.getParent();
                    oldParent.removeView(view);

                       LinearLayout newParent = (LinearLayout) v;
                       newParent.addView(view);     
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }    
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
        v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);    
        return true;
    }    
}
```

И еще одна просьба, не могли бы вы пояснить, логику этой записи:

```
View view = (View)event.getLocalState();
                LinearLayout oldParent = (LinearLayout)view.getParent();
                oldParent.removeView(view);

                   LinearLayout newParent = (LinearLayout) v;
                   newParent.addView(view);
```

В данном случае создаем переменную типа View, но вот почему именно такая запись:

```
View view = (View)event.getLocalState();
```

Что за значение в этом случае получает эта переменная?